# Child nodes are not getting listed in SparkTree (kachurovskiy) component

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, tree, flex4, flex4.5

I'm using the SparkTree (4.0) component (http://kachurovskiy.com/2010/spark-tree/) as I was facing some issue with the mx:Tree component.

I'm having a xml data which I'm converting to a xmllistcollection and assigning to the dataprovider property of the SparkTree component. It was not rendering properly. Later, after reading several FAQ's posted for the SparkTree component, I realised that the tree will behave ideally for an arraycollection instead of xml/xmllist/xmlcollection.

So, I converted the xml data into an arraycollection and assigned it to the dataprovider of the SparkTree. Still, then only the top level nodes are displayed as leaf nodes and no child nodes are displayed.`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
               minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               xmlns:sparkTree="com.sparkTree.*" >
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.collections.XMLListCollection;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.rpc.xml.SimpleXMLDecoder;
            import mx.utils.ArrayUtil;

            [Bindable]
            private var dlist:XMLListCollection;

            [Bindable]
            private var dColln:ArrayCollection;

            [Bindable]
            private var dashColln:ArrayCollection; 

            [Bindable]
            private var dashListColln:ArrayCollection; 

            protected function sparkTree_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                var dashList:XMLList=XMLList(testxml.children());
                var mydecoder:SimpleXMLDecoder=new SimpleXMLDecoder();
                var data:Object=mydecoder.decodeXML(new XMLDocument(dashList.toXMLString()));
                dashListColln = new ArrayCollection();
                if (data != null && data.menu.length > 0) {
                    for (var i:int=0; i<data.menu.length; i++) {
                        dashColln = new ArrayCollection(Array(data.menu[i]));
                        dashListColln.addAll(dashColln);
                    }
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <fx:XML id="testxml" source="xml/Test.xml" />
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:Panel width="75%" height="75%" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">
        <sparkTree:Tree id="sparkTree" 
                        dataProvider="{dashListColln}"
                        creationComplete="sparkTree_creationCompleteHandler(event)"
                        width="100%"
                        height="100%"
                        textRollOverColor="yellow" 
                        textSelectedColor="0xFFFFFF" dragEnabled="true" dropEnabled="true"
                        dragMoveEnabled="true">
            <!--<sparkTree:layout>
            <s:TileLayout horizontalGap="0" verticalGap="0" orientation="columns"/>
            </sparkTree:layout>-->
        </sparkTree:Tree>
    </s:Panel>

</s:Application>
```

`

```
   <root>

    <menu label="A">
        <menu label="A1">
             <menu label="A1.1" />
        </menu>
        <menu label="A2" >
            <menu label="A2.2"/>
        </menu>
        <menu label="A3" >
            <menu label="A3.3"/>
        </menu>
        <menu label="A4" >
            <menu label="A4.4"/>
        </menu>
    </menu>
    <menu label="B">
        <menu label="B1" />
        <menu label="B2" />
        <menu label="B3" />
    </menu>
    <menu label="C">
        <menu label="C1" />
        <menu label="C2" />
        <menu label="C3" />
    </menu>
    <menu label="D">
        <menu label="D1" />
        <menu label="D2" />
    </menu>
    <menu label="E">
        <menu label="E1" />
    </menu>

</root>
```

Kindly, Please share your thoughts on this. **Why I'm not getting the child nodes even the arraycollection has the child objects ?**
[image]

Comment: What was the problem with the XMLListCollection? I think the way through the ArrayCollection is not the best one. Is it here what you want to get? http://it-skills.su/sosamples/webspark46/treexml/index.html

Answer (score 0):

try this  ..
This is a more elegant solution ...
It has a data flattner as well ..
So that you dont have to handle the XML data formatting ..

http://saturnboy.com/2011/09/spark-treelist/